# Export my analytics data and put them in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, google-analytics

I am looking to export the analytics data towards a database sql. Do you know one tools who could help me?

Do you know how I can see on Google analytics the traffic resulting from a particular URL??

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- **UI export**: in the top/right corner of your reports you should have an option to download data in various formats (XLS, CSV...)
- **API**: [you can use the reporting API to get it out](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) in a programmatic/automated way

`One thing you won't be able to do with the free version no matter what you try`:

- **Reconstruct the entire analytics data**: whether with the UI or API, you're limited to querying only 7 dimensions maximum at a time (eg `ga:country`, `ga:deviceCategory` etc...), and cannot combine certain dimensions together (no official list available, it's trial and error to find out), whereas [there are dozens of dimensions available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

So the question for you becomes:

- How much resources do I want to invest into partially reverse-engineering Google Analytics vs. the value it brings me vs. what it would cost to get alternative analytics solutions?

Comment: I agree with @Max's last point to a large extent, but it does rather depend what the OP wants the data /for/ - it may be that the limited export capability of the free version does the job for them. GA does of course have limitations but I for one have been pleasantly surprised by how much I can do with it, relatively easily, without charge, especially when using it alongside Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [cloud based solution](https://electrik.ai/product/google-analytics-hit-data-extractor) which exports raw google analytics data to MySQL database. Setup is simple, all you need to do is add your Google Analytics connection and a database to which the data needs to be exported.

MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server and BigQuery are the supported destinations. It creates a few custom dimensions in your Google Analytics account and Tag in Google Tag Manager to send hits to Google Analytics. Data is exported from Google Analytics to the selected destination every day.

I have been using it for last three months now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the analytics data is a thorny one.

My understanding is that paid GA usage allows the export of all collected GA data.

But free usage does not.

For free usage, all you are going to be able to do, realistically, is to create a report over your GA data (in Data Studio or Google Sheets) that contains the rows and columns you want, and then collect this information and squirt it into a SQL table. You are also liable to come up against sampling.

Re traffic from particular URL, the news is better: just filter on Hostname and Page.