# How do I import data from Google Analysis into a local database and how much data the free version of Google Analysis can hold?

Tags: analysis

Questions about Google Analysis:
How do I import data from Google Analysis into a local database?
How much data does the free version of Google Analysis hold?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider using the search. Please ask one question at once. Please provide some example of what you've tried, what's working and what's not working

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question one: There's an [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) (via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22154364/3890673) and especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906849/3890673) answers)

Regarding question two: You'll find information about the limitations [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas).